# how to create gcp projects without default network using gcloud sdk

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, default, gcloud

For terraform there is an option "auto_create_network = false" to skip creation of a default net within a new project.

Is there also an option/flag for gcloud sdk / gcloud projects create (e.g. `--skip-default-network`)? Or must we use org policy `constraints/compute.skipDefaultNetworkCreation` (https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terraform's solution is to delete the default network promptly after creation:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_project.html#auto_create_network

Therefore, you:

- either use the org policy to never create it
- or (you do what Terraform does and) `gcloud compute networks delete` it after creation:

#### Example

> Please test this in a sacrificial project to ensure it meets your needs

```sh
gcloud compute firewall-rules list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--filter="network:/projects/${PROJECT}/global/networks/default" \
--format="value(name)"  \
| xargs gcloud compute firewall-rules delete \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--quiet

gcloud compute networks delete default \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--quiet
```